# VBA Convert format conditions for different sheets to a loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I'm seeking for a way to convert the following format conditions to a loop for coding efficiency. I thought about putting Table in an array, but it seems not much improvement with the repeated table names.

The conditioned format is very simple. It is just highlighting cells with values between 5 to 10 and -5 to -10.

Any insights will be helpful!

```
With y.Sheets("Table 1").Range("P:P").FormatConditions.Add (Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=5", Formula2:="10")
.Interior.Color = rgbYellow
 End With
With y.Sheets("Table 1").Range("P:P").FormatConditions.Add (Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=-5", Formula2:="-10")
.Interior.Color = rgbYellow
 End With
With y.Sheets("Table 2").Range("P:P").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=5", Formula2:="10")
.Interior.Color = rgbYellow
 End With
With y.Sheets("Table 2").Range("P:P").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=-5", Formula2:="-10")
.Interior.Color = rgbYellow
 End With
With y.Sheets("Table 3").Range("P:P").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=5", Formula2:="10")
.Interior.Color = rgbYellow
 End With
With y.Sheets("Table 3").Range("P:P").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=-5", Formula2:="-10")
.Interior.Color = rgbYellow
 End With
With y.Sheets("Table 7").Range("P:P").FormatConditions.Add (Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=5", Formula2:="10")
.Interior.Color = rgbYellow
 End With
With y.Sheets("Table 7").Range("P:P").FormatConditions.Add (Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=-5", Formula2:="-10")
.Interior.Color = rgbYellow
 End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub test()

Dim xl_sheet As Worksheet

For Each xl_sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If xl_sheet.Name Like "Table*" Then

    With xl_sheet
    .Range("P:P").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=5", Formula2:="10").Interior.Color = rgbYellow
    .Range("P:P").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=-5", Formula2:="-10").Interior.Color = rgbYellow
    End With

    End If


 Next xl_sheet

End Sub
```

Comment: it worked after I replaced `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: I'm just wondering if I add a `AND` statement will the `Like` function still work? Such as `If xl_sheet.Name Like "Table*" And "ABC" Then`. I received run time error 13, type mismatch.

Comment: You need to repeat the variable you want to test, `If xl_sheet.Name Like "Table*" And xl_sheet.Name Like "ABC*" Then`

Comment: I tried to use `If xl_sheet.Name Like "Table*" And xl_sheet.Name Like "ABC*" Then` and `If xl_sheet.Name Like "Table*" And xl_sheet.Name = "ABC" Then` There was no errors, but the format conditions does not show up as if nothing happened. It only show up when I remove the second part of `And` condition statement. I checked I have all the tabs recalled in condition statement.

Comment: I think my mistake was I should have used `or` instead. Thank you for helping me !